# Im trying to drop a pin but I get this error: Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationManager' to type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func drop(sender: AnyObject)
{
     let mapAnnotation        = MKPointAnnotation()
     mapAnnotation.coordinate = locationManager   //  Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationManager' to type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'
     mapAnnotation.title      = "If you want a title"
     mapAnnotation.subtitle   = "or subtitle"
     myMap.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you can't assign a `CLLocationManager` object to a property of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

You need to change the code to:

```
mapAnnotation.coordinate = locationManager.location!.coordinate
```

The `location` property can be `nil` due to various reasons and forced unwrapping will result in a crash. So it will be better to use safe unwrapping:

```
if let loc = locationManager.location
{
   mapAnnotation.coordinate = loc.coordinate
}
```

References:

1. [MKPointAnnotation - coordinate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPointAnnotation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPointAnnotation/coordinate)
2. [CLLocationManager - location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location)

Comment: Actually the simulator stopped and I got Thread 1 Exc Bad Instruction

Comment: @SonnySluiter: That was due to forced unwrapping, you should use safe unwrapping instead, please check the updated answer